# For science and tech, is there really a practical reason to linearize equations before plotting to find constants?

Tags: numerical-methods, regression

I understand that if you have a lot of equations that it will speed up computation time.

But I often see in papers someone will linearize something like the Michaelis Menten equation to then solve for the constants in it from a linear fit rather than simply using a non linear fit to the original equation. Is there some other reason they would do this that I am missing, it just seems like an extra step?

Comment: Most of the usual solvers proceed by first computing some kind of linearization and then solving the linear system to find the next iteration point. Using the structure of the problem might speed up and/or simplify the linearization process compared with a black-box approach. I'd guess that may be a reason why the linearization is explicitly provided.

Comment: @LutzL but in a case where they're only calculating like 10 values let's say and the equation isn't that nasty (e.g. V = Vm*S/(Km +S) solving for Vm and Km). Do you see any reason to not just solve this equation numerically directly?